# sas macro in proc sql

Tags: sql, macros, sas, proc

i have a problem that probably very simple but i can't figured out.

i have columns `name1 c1 c2 c3 c4 .... c8` i have to sum by names these columns and make a new data.

Here is the code that i wrote but it didnt work.

Could you please help me?

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.data1 AS 
   SELECT t1.name1, 

%let k=8
%macro test;
%do i=0 %to &k;
%sysfunc(SUM(C&i)) AS C&i;
%END;
%mend test;
%test;
      FROM WORK.data t1
      GROUP BY t1.name1,
QUIT;
```

Comment: And maybe have a look at this paper: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/243-29.pdf

Comment: ok i will study this. thank you very much

Comment: No problem :) Hint: Missing semicolon after %let and use of sysfunc at this point is not necessary.    
And you can use mprint in combination with mfile to get a file containing the base code wich is generated by the macro code. Very useful for debuging and learning.

Comment: i am very new and realy feel like in an ocean :). mprint and mfile in my search list now. thank you.

Comment: Yeah, SAS is a little bit confusing in the beginning, but its a really great tool for certain tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data data;
input name1 $ c1 c2 c3;
datalines4;
a 1 2 3
a 1 2 3
b 1 2 3
b 1 2 3
;;;;
run;

%macro test(k=);
  PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.data1 AS 
   SELECT t1.name1 

%do i=1 %to &k.;
   , SUM(C&i.) AS C&i.
%END;

  FROM WORK.data t1
  GROUP BY t1.name1;
QUIT;

%mend test;
%test(k=3);
```

Comment: why should i use comma before "SUM(C&i.) AS C&i." and what the means of these dots? Could you help me?

Comment: If you put the comma after "SUM(C&i.) AS C&i." then you would get a comm after the last generated variable (in my example after c3), which would result in a Syntax error. So dont put any comma outside the macro loop, to avoid this.  
The dot after the macrovariable name is in most cases not necessary. It tells the macroprocessor that the name of the macro variable ends there. I think its in most cases good to put the dot, even if you dont have to, because of readability and clearness.

Comment: Try to execute the following code before the macro code:
`Filename mprint "~/generated_code.sas"; Options mprint mfile;`
This will give you plain base code without macrocode in the file generated_code.sas .

Answer (score 1):

This seems a convoluted way of achieving your result, PROC SUMMARY can do it much easier utilising the colon modifier to sum all variables beginning with C. The code below runs off the dataset created by @Mike and produces identical output.

```
proc summary data=data nway;
class name1;
var c: ;
output out=want (drop=_:) sum=;
run;
```

Comment: very smart solution also.thank you.it works. but i have to deal with other columns starting with 'c'.but no problem thank you again.

Comment: Then just change the var statement to c1-c3 (or c1-c8 in your example)